# What happened to the package tangle index in SonarQube 5.0?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have a cyclical dependency that's preventing Maven from building so I upgraded my SonarQube installation (old 4.6 installation would fail with transport exceptions) to 5.0, and I cannot find the package tangle index.

The only bit I can find on it is this article from [SonarQube 2.0](http://www.sonarqube.org/fight-back-design-erosion-by-breaking-cycles-with-sonar/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for 5.0, but this feature has been removed in 5.2. 
All needed details an be found here :  https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6553